# What is `a[start:stop, i]` in Python slicing?

Tags: python, list, slice, built-in

Python doc for [built-in function `slice`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice) is (emphasis mine):

> `class slice(stop)`
> `class slice(start, stop[, step])`
>
> Return a slice object representing the set of indices specified by `range(start, stop, step)`. The `start` and `step` arguments default to `None`. Slice objects have read-only data attributes `start`, `stop` and `step` which merely return the argument values (or their default). They have no other explicit functionality; however they are used by NumPy and other third party packages. **Slice objects are also generated when extended indexing syntax is used. For example: `a[start:stop:step]` or `a[start:stop, i]`. See `itertools.islice()` for an alternate version that returns an iterator.**

What does `a[start:stop, i]` mean?

I tried it out (in Python 3.6):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a[1:3,1]
```

but got:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: It means something different depending on `a`. If `a` is a list, it is not valid, as you have seen.

Comment: the docs are unclear but you can do it in numpy, it means roughly select column 1 in rows 1:3

Comment: maybe it's just a typo in the docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot combine `:` and `,` with lists.

`:` is for direct slicing:

```
a[1:3:1]
```

`,` is used with `slice`:

```
a[slice(1,3,1)]
```

However with objects supporting it (like numpy arrays) you can slice in several dimensions:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0,1,3],[3,4,5]])
a[0:1,2]
```

output: `array([3])`

Comment: You can, `a[1:2, 3]` is shorthand for`a.__getitem__((slice(1, 2, None), 3))`, which other classes may support (look at numpy for lots of examples). `list` just can't handle that.

Comment: @mata I thought the question was for lists, I'll update

Comment: Did you see that `a[start:stop, i]` is straight from the Python docs as cites by the OP?